# How to read from stdin without copying the last entered command?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to read from stdin such that I can use the `piped cat` output of a text file--with the command

```
cat lines_of_text.txt | ./a.out
```

but the program I have is reprinting the last entered command, such that it first reads back

```
./a.out
```

before printing the contents of `lines_of_text.txt`. How do I only print the contents of lines_of_text.txt and not `"./a.out"`? Below is my program and a screenclip of my terminal:

```
int main() {
    FILE* file = stdin;
    char* inputText;
    char line[128];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        strncat(inputText, line, 128);
    }
    fputs(inputText, stdout);
    fputs("\n", stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: screenclip of terminal]

Comment: `strncat(inputText, line, 128);` results in undefined behaviour becasue `inputText` is not initialised and thus has a random value.

Comment: `cat` starts an unneeded process and less efficient pipe, by the way – you can pipe directly from the file with `< lines_of_text.txt ./a.out` (or equivalent `./a.out < lines_of_text.txt`). [Redirections (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Comment: Also, even after initializing `inputText` to point to some allocated memory, `strncat` onto an ever-lengthening string in a loop is inefficient. You should keep a pointer to the end of the string instead, copy onto it, and move the pointer to the new end.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `inputText` with `malloc()`. You can increase the size with `realloc()` as you read more lines. After you allocate memory, you also have to make sure it starts with a null byte so that `strncat()` will work.

Comment: strncat here is a 'schlemeil the painter'  algorithm https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Answer (score 1):

In your program, you read correctly a line of text into `line` variable, but for some reason you then copy it to the position pointed by an uninitialised pointer (`inputText`) which makes  `strncat` to write it in memory you don't know where, resulting in Undefined Behaviour.  From this point on, you can expect almost any weird thing, being the most common a crash of your program.

You don't need to copy the string inside the loop, but in case you would want to copy, you need to reserve some space for it in another array (the pointer itself doesn't allocate the needed memory), as you can print it from the same address as the original `line` buffer, as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* use the include headers */

int main()
{
    FILE* file = stdin;
    char* inputText;
    char line[128];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        /* this will print the '\n' also (you read it) */
        fputs(line, stdout);
    }
    /* no need to do more after the loop */
    return 0;
}
```

you need to print the `line` buffer from the inside of the loop.

In case you want to copy:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* use the include headers */
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE    128

int main()
{
    FILE* file = stdin;
    char* inputText;
    char line[SIZE], copy_of_line[SIZE];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        /* this will print the '\n' also (you read it) */
        strncpy(copy_of_line, line, sizeof copy_of_line);
        fputs(copy_of_line, stdout);
    }
    /* no need to do more after the loop */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First problem is that if you print an array without "clean" it is an UB and you will print some garbage, second, is that also if you don't allocate nothing to inputText and use it in strncat is an UB, thi is my correction to the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 128

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE* file = stdin;
  char* inputText;
  char* line;

  line = calloc(BUF_SIZE,sizeof(char));
  inputText = calloc(BUF_SIZE,sizeof(char));
  for (int i = 1;fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL; inputText = realloc(inputText,BUF_SIZE * i), i++) {
    strncat(inputText, line, BUF_SIZE);
  }

  fputs(inputText, stdout);
  fputs("\n", stdout);

  free(line);
  free(inputText);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are still calling `strnact()` with a not initialized pointer.

Comment: And `inputText`?

Comment: Now the allocated memory pointed to by `inputText` will overflow. The OP shows at least 6 lines of 24 characters, in total 144 characters. -- Did you ever try your program?

Comment: no he will not overflow, strncat appends the string pointed to by src to the end of the string pointed to by dest up to n characters long, i tried the program with an input file of 12 lines and 168 characters and it works great, maybe at most it can truncate some output with too large files but this was obvious

Comment: Please read the documentation of `strncat()`! You are appending at most `BUF_SIZE`, the destination space needs to be big enough to store the previous string *and the appended string*. Try again with 120 lines.

Comment: With a file of 144 line and 2016 characters the program work perfectly, try it from yourself if you want.

Comment: Well, it's not my duty to prove the error in your program, it is obvious. You are just lucky that the buffer overrun does not crash you program. Test more, for example with some thousands of lines, or swap the lines with `calloc()` and/or swap the lines with `free()`. Both swaps should not make any difference in a correct program.

Comment: The point is that it's obvious that he shouldn't use file with more of 128 elements, i used a 128 element buf size because he used in his example a 128 element buffer, so if he use a more big buffer is his problem (he should just add one line of code, where calling realloc)

Comment: You misunderstood the 128. The OP uses this limit *just for the single line of input*. There is no limit for `inputText` in his source.

Comment: ah, i understand what you are seeing i misunderstood what he was seeing i can add the realloc

Comment: i think that now it can be correct or at least i hope

Comment: It still has some flaws, but you're on your way. All the best!